# Checking for Skew Lines

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

> How do we check given two vectors, say $a_1\hat{i}+b_1\hat{j}+c_1\hat{k}$ and $a_2\hat{i}+b_2\hat{j}+c_2\hat{k}$ are skew lines ?

I understand that skew lines are those which are neither intersecting nor parallel. i.e, non-coplanar and not intersecting.

So,

I was wondering, can I check it a skew line directly, without checking for whether it is coplanar or intersecting ?

Comment: But it is simple to check whether two lines are intersecting or parallel, isn't it? If you can rule out both, then the lines will be skew.

Comment: Vectors are vectors, they can be collinear or not, which you check with a cross-product. But they don't define lines (or just lines from the origin). So your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: No matter how you specify the lines, the test for non-skewness will be mathematically equivalent to testing whether they are parallel and coplanar. (Which, by the way, is very simple, and computationally extremely cheap, so the question does not make sense in this regard either.)